# Postgres GROUP BY with count returns integer for text

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres table which is a log of every page request on our site.

I am trying to write a simple query in pgAdmin 4 to return a count of how many times each page was hit.

```
SELECT Title, Count(*) FROM Log GROUP BY Title
```

I also tried

```
SELECT Title, Count(Title) FROM Log GROUP BY Title
```

What gets returned however is

```
Title            Count
*text*           *big int* 

1000             12
10000            8  
10001            20
10002            32
. . . 
10019            23
1002             6
10021            34
10022            41
```

..and so on.

There is no rhyme or reason for this that I can think of.

`Title` is a text field.

What I would like to see is

```
Home    45
About   23
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it really *is* a number. You probably know the database from using it with an apolication, and that application joins `log` with a different table that contains the titles in text form.

You probably need a statement along the lines of:

```
SELECT t.title, count(*)
FROM log AS l
   JOIN titles as t ON l.title = t.id
GROUP BY t.id, t. title;
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I posted this question last Friday. Weekend has past and I'm back at work now.  I just tried this again.

It worked perfectly. No sign of the numbers where the titles should be.

Maybe this was a software glitch on pgAdmin. Maybe I just needed to restart the postgres service (that is a pretty dire bug if it happened on a live server)

Laurenz, this is just a log table. I've seen the code that writes it. There is just this one table.

Was the oddest db glitch. The numbers as you can see in the post above were in some order, but not like id values.,

1000, 10000, 10001 > 19999, 2000, 20000, 20001, 29999

Bizarre.

Anyway, thanks to everyone who read this and thanks for replying Laurenz.

I think this issue is solved.. Restart the service.